# How do I perform a silent authentication between windows 7 and JBoss 4.2.3?

Tags: authentication, windows-7, jboss, active-directory, single-sign-on

I have developed a web based java application that is deployed on JBOSS 4.2.3 Solaris environment.it authenticates the users through windows active directory. The user use the same windows log-in credential to access the application. I need to perform a **silent authentication** between the internet explorer on **windows 7** and JBoss in order to set SSO experience at the user. I know that NTLM v1 is not supported any more by windows 7.  Appreciate your support

Comment: Is this a theoretical investigation, or do you in practice see a sign-in dialog from IE on Windows 7 which you want to go away?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to configure the app to accept Kerberos authentication. Sorry I don't have any experience with JBOSS to tell you how, but, at a high level you'd create a service account in AD for the app, add a SPN for http/url.to.jboss.app.goes.here.com and then configure the server to make use of this service account and point it to your DCs for their KDCs.